# Run more than one update statement at one time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE TableName  SET 'OldName1' = 'New Name1' WHERE ID = 1
UPDATE TableName  SET 'OldName2' = 'New Name2' WHERE ID = 2
UPDATE TableName  SET 'OldName3' = 'New Name3' WHERE ID = 3`
UPDATE TableName  SET 'OldName4' = 'New Name4' WHERE ID = 4
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: This is possible with a single UPDATE

Comment: Hi Dale,  I didn't even try it yet.  How can I do in a single statement.   lsanchezo if possible do in one statement I can try that.

Comment: Your statements are invalid, column names are not treated as string literals, presumably *OldName1* is a column? It should be just `OldName1`.

Comment: @Stu that is correct it should have just said Name for the column.  Dale I did just try it and it did work with using multiple rows at one time.

Comment: If this "How can I do in a single statement." is your actual question, then you need to clarify your question because its not clear that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a single update by using a *case expression*, like so:

```
update TableName set
  OldName1 = case when id = 1 then 'New Name1' else OldName1 end
  OldName2 = case when id = 2 then 'New Name2' else OldName2 end
  OldName3 = case when id = 3 then 'New Name3' else OldName3 end
  OldName4 = case when id = 4 then 'New Name4' else OldName4 end
where Id between 1 and 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a "set" of rows you want to update. That idea should lead you to using a table in some fashion. In this case we can use a temp table of some type or a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The constructor is a very handy of dynamically creating a table for a single query.

You put your rows of "updates" in such a constructor and then simply join to it for the update. Example:

```
update tod 
set name = v.name 
from tod inner join (values (1, 'new bbb'), (2, 'new ccc'), 
   (3, 'new ddd'), (4, 'new zzz')) v(id, name)
on tod.id = v.id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=179cbcb02e25653a17bf334a86ebbbdd) to demonstrate. Here "tod" is your table aptly named "TableName".